# Close lock screen by pressing any key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lock-screen

In Windows 8.1, after waking up the computer, I could press (almost) any key to go from the lock screen to the login screen.

Now, in Windows 10, this only works for the lock screen triggered by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. The lock screen after waking up the computer is only closable by either pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or by clicking with the mouse.

The option "Secure sign-in" in the Advanced User Accounts Control Panel, as described in [this answer](//superuser.com/a/494296/171882), is unchecked.

How can I get back the behavior of Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this is for anyone else reading this. So you do not have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to go from the lock screen to the logon screen you need to:

Open the `Run` box (<kbd>Windows</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd>)> Type `Secpol.msc` > `Local Policies` > Click on `Security Options` > navigate to and double click on `Interactive Logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL` > and `Enable` it